# Monobehaviour scripts in the file, or their names don't match the file name on newly made script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

Why all my newly created script always have this error? Even though i had put in my intended code, all my script always show like this.
my code is this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Testing : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject obj;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        obj = GetComponent<GameObject>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        collision.transform.position = obj.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual error? When you create a new c# file in Unity the class is named whatever you name the file. It isn't clear if that is what you're talking about or not.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oqH4jEQ

Comment: Its always showing like that, i dont know what's wrong with my code that it cannot be added to the sprite. I checked what MonoBehaviour is and OnTriggerEnter2D is one of it, so im not sure where i go wrong.

Comment: When i tried to create new script through "New component", the script always not recognized instantly, and when i try to put it back, it goes like that. every single new script.

Comment: Your error is for a script called `AssemblyInfo` and you've shown us `Testing`

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

This issue is mostly caused when you create a script outside the Unity Editor, i.e. in your IDE or editor of choice. Whenever you want to create a script, you need to create it inside the Editor, by **right-clicking** in your project folder and selecting "**New C# Script**".

If you do create your script inside Unity, you need to make sure that the class name (in your case, "Testing") **is the same as the script file name**.

Regardless of whether these solutions work for you, please make sure to search for answers before posting, as there are multiple duplicate issues in the Unity forums.